# IOPub data rate exceeded in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipython

When I read a txt into jupyter notebook, it told me that the data rate exceeded, and I try some code, but it did not work.

```
with open("wiki.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
    print(data)
```

```
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.
```

Current values:

```
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
```

Then I tried some code, but it still did not work.

```
--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10
```

```
Input In [32]
--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10
^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current set up jupyter has iopub_data_rate_limit as 1000000

Try increasing it if feasible. Also exponent doesn't work i believe.

You can try below it will relaunch the jupyter notebook with iopub_data_rate_limit as 2000000

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=20000000
```